# How do you create an outdoor map without letting in leaks?

Tags: source-engine

With the Source engine, I want to make a map in the outdoors (similar to something like Dust2 or Inferno) but not let in leaks due to the open top part of the map. Is there a way I can do it without the leaks?

Comment: Having used Source, I can say with utmost certainty that the engine doesn't support that kind of environment. Every level needs to be contained in a box, be it a Skybox or what have you. It's just the way the engine operates. Granted, you could just have one massive skybox.

Comment: @Krythic If you want to post an answer, post one. Posting a comment and getting upset when people post an answer with similar ideas isn't reasonable. Post your answer and the community can decide by votes which is best for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with a **skybox**. In reality, the maps are still closed; they are simply using a special material which marks the space as to render the skybox, which is what ends up looking like the sky. Therefore, you must enclose the level with the "tools/toolsskybox" texture, while leaving sufficient space for things like grenade throws to happen. There are multiple versions of skyboxes, I suggest you read through the VDC article [here.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Skybox_Basics)